# How do i prevent the player from sinking into the floor in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

In my game in python, I am trying to make jumping work, but the player sinks 1-2 pixels into the floor, and I do not know the fix.
My code is:

```
    import pygame
    
    
    objs = []
    pygame.init()
    
    
    class Clock:
        def __init__(self):
            self.tps = 30
            self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    
    clock = Clock()
    
    
    class Text:
        def __init__(self):
            self.font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
            self.e = 0
            self.text = self.font.render(f'GAME OVER! | Score: {self.e}', True, (255, 0, 0))
            self.textRect = self.text.get_rect()
            self.X = 400
            self.Y = 400
            self.textRect.center = (self.X // 2, self.Y // 2)
    
    
    text = Text()
    
    
    class Screen:
        def __init__(self):
            self.colour = 0, 0, 0
            self.size = 500
            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.size, self.size))
    
    
    screen = Screen()
    
    
    class Floor:
        def __init__(self):
            self.colour = 0, 0, 255
            self.width = 500
            self.height = 50
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 400
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
            objs.append(self.rect)
    
    
        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen.screen, self.colour, self.rect)
    
    
        def update(self):
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
            self.draw()
    
    
    floor = Floor()
    
    
    class Pillar:
        def __init__(self):
            self.colour = 255, 0, 0
            self.width = 50
            self.height = 100
            self.x = 100
            self.y = 300
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
            self.speed = 1
    
    
        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen.screen, self.colour, self.rect)
    
    
        def update(self):
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
            self.draw()
    
    
        def move(self):
            if self.x < 500:
                self.x += self.speed
            else:
                for _ in range(screen.size):
                    self.x -= self.speed
                    player.points += 1
    
    
    pillar = Pillar()
    
    
    class Player:
        def __init__(self):
            self.colour = 0, 255, 0
            self.size = 50
            self.x = 250
            self.y = 250
            self.speed = 5
            self.jump_speed = 10
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size)
            self.fall_speed = 5
            self.grounded = False
            self.jump_height = 10
            self.jumping = False
            self.points = 0
            self.debug_mode = False
    
    
        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen.screen, self.colour, self.rect)
    
    
        def update(self):
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size)
            self.draw()
    
    
        def jump(self):
            if self.grounded:
                for _ in range(self.jump_height):
                    self.jumping = True
                    self.y -= self.jump_speed
                self.jumping = False
                print(self.y)
    
    
        def gravity(self):
            if not self.grounded and not self.jumping:
                self.y += (self.fall_speed - 1)
    
    
        def check_collision_objs(self):
            if self.rect.collidelistall(objs):
                self.grounded = True
            else:
                self.grounded = False
    
    
        def check_collision_deads(self):
            if not self.debug_mode:
                if self.rect.colliderect(pillar.rect):
                    text.e = self.points
                    screen.screen.blit(text.text, text.textRect)
                else:
                    self.update()
    
    
        def left(self):
            self.x -= self.speed
    
    
        def right(self):
            self.x += self.speed
    
    
        def debug(self):
            print("debug on")
            self.jump_height = self.jump_height * 2
    
    
    player = Player()
    
    
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
    
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                player.jump()
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                player.left()
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                player.right()
            if keys[pygame.K_z]:
                player.debug()
    
    
        screen.screen.fill(screen.colour)
        player.gravity()
        player.check_collision_objs()
        player.check_collision_deads()
        floor.update()
        pillar.move()
        pillar.update()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.clock.tick(clock.tps)
```

I expected it to stay on the top pixel, but it goes into the block slightly.
I tried making it push the player 1 above the block with self.y -= 1, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Sooo, `floor` is a 500 × 50 rectangle at (0, 400),
and `player` is a mobile 50 × 50 square.
You're upset that the floor is "squishy" like quicksand,
and the player penetrates it by a couple pixels.

Here's the `grounded` test:

```
        def check_collision_objs(self):
            if self.rect.collidelistall(objs):
```

You set a boolean.
(It would suffice to assign `self.grounded = self.rect....`.)

It's kind of "too late" at that point -- the player
has already started to merge into the floor.
Here is how the player descends:

```
        def gravity(self):
            if not self.grounded and not self.jumping:
                self.y += self.fall_speed - 1
```

Not sure what's good about that `-1` -- just set speed to `4`
instead of `5` if that's what you want.

Notice that `y` can plummet at high speed, right through the floor.
We don't test or adjust anything, but we need to.
Here is *one* approach:

```
        def gravity(self):
            if not self.grounded and not self.jumping:
                assert self.fall_speed > 0
                self.y += self.fall_speed

                # If we just sank into the floor then rise by a few pixels.
                while self.rect.collidelistall(objs):
                    self.y -= 1
```

An alternate approach would examine the difference between the
floor and player y's, and decrement by that much, without a `while` loop.

Another approach would be to create an invisible `carpet`, with height of 1 pixel,
immediately above the floor.
Then we can ask if player collides with the carpet.
This seems to offer little advantage for `fall_speed`s greater than one,
since we still need to adjust player's `y` by some number of pixels.
We wouldn't want to replace your complaint of "player sank a few pixels
into the floor" with a similar complaint of "player hovers a random
number pixels above the floor".